# Not able to run Python 2.7 code in python 3.8 compiler in Pi4 board

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.8, pi, thonny

I have a project which is coded in python 2.7. Before setting up the project I should install few libraries for the project using sudo pip install.

These installs are default installing in python 2.7. However I have python 3 compiler(Thonny) in my rapsberry pi4 board. When I run the code it is throwing an error saying Import Error.

As I said before those imports are in python2.7.
How can I over come this issue. I am not able to find any python2.7 compilers for rapsberry pi4. My idea is to download python2.7 compilers and run the code. Will this work? is there any python2.7 compiler for rapsberry pi4?. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a python module called 2to3, I havent used it personally but it may help you get you code running in python3. Docs are here https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/2to3.html